# Understanding and Using $P(X\in dx)$

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables, density-function

I haven't found a satisfactory explanation of the meaning of $P(X\in dx)$.

I believe it means $P(x\le X \le x+dx)=\int _x ^{x+dx}f(t)dt$  where $f$ is the density. However, the meaning of $dx$ is ambiguous to me, and I don't see how to use this to computute a pdf.

Can I obtain a precice definition of this expression and see how it is used to compute the PDF of any well-known distribution?

Comment: I'd write $P(x\le X\le x+dx) = f(x)\,dx$. $\qquad$

Comment: Can you tell us where you're seeing this notation?

Comment: @AJY page 4 (equation (3)) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.2729v2.pdf

Comment: Hm. Are you familiar with the concept of a Radon-Nikodym derivative?